# cl.exe が壊れたバイナリしか出力しない

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

Windows の MSVC を初めて使用します。 ( macOS/Linux で GCC/Clang は使ったことがあります)
簡単な次のファイルを cl.exe でコンパイルしようと思います。

prog.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;

}
```

コンパイルのコマンドは

```
cl.exe /EHsc /Feprog.exe prog.c
```

すると、 prog.obj と prog.exe が特に問題なく生成されたように思われます。
ところが prog.exe は実行できません。 prog.exe の内容を Hex 表示すると 000000 (ヌル文字) がひたすら続くファイルになっています。
どうしたら適切に実行できるバイナリが生成できるか教えていただけませんでしょうか。

インストールした開発環境

- MSVC v143 x64/x86 ビルド
- Visual Studio Community 2022
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)
- Windows 11 21H2

### 追記

情報が不足していて申し訳ありません。

- 作業環境は Visual Studio Code で、統合ターミナルから次の batch ファイルを実行してコマンドプロンプトを開きました

```
@echo off
%COMSPEC% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
```

このコマンドプロンプト内で `cl.exe /EHsc /Feprog.exe prog.c` を実行しています。

- Developer Command Prompt / Developer PowerShell でも試してみましたが同様の結果です。 `.\prog.exe` に対して `指定されたプログラムは実行できません。` と返ってきます。
- `cl.exe` の出力メッセージは次の通りです

```
Microsoft(R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31104 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

prog.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.31.31104.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:prog.exe 
prog.obj
```

- prog.obj はヌル文字のみのファイルではなかったので、 `link.exe` に問題があるんじゃないかと思っています。 `link.exe prog.obj /out:prog.exe` も試してみたら、毎度ヌル文字の prog.exe が生成されます。 link.exe の出力は次の通り。

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.31.31104.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

- `dir` の出力でディレクトリ構成を説明します。

```
 Directory of C:\Users\*\prog

2022/02/24  12:18    <DIR>          .
2022/02/24  12:17    <DIR>          ..
2022/02/24  12:18           101,888 prog.exe
2022/02/24  12:18                94 prog.c
2022/02/24  12:18             1,433 prog.obj
               3 File(s)        105,175 bytes
```

- 基本的に Visual Studio を使わずに CLI 上でコンパイルを行いたいので、 Visual Studio の動作確認をあまりしていないのですが、動作確認はした方がよいのでしょうか。

### 追記2

- ご指摘の通り、上記では間違って x86 の Developer Command Prompt を使っていました。確かに x64 だとこういう出力になります。

```
Microsoft(R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31104 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

prog.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.31.31104.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:prog.exe
prog.obj
```

どちらにしても壊れた実行ファイルが生成され続けます。
Visual Studio 2022 を一旦削除して、再びインストールしてみたのですが、やはり変わっていません。

- Visual Studio のプロジェクト (コンソール アプリ) を作って、特に書き換えずそのまま「デバッグなしで開始」を押してみたのですが

```
プログラム `<実行ファイルの場所>` を開始できません。
ファイルまたはディレクトリが壊れているため、読み取ることができません。
```

というダイアログが表示されて実行できませんでした。

- あとセキュリティソフトはインストールしていない環境です。インストールしているアプリの中から疑わしいものを探してみます。
- Mac の MinGW-w64 の GCC で作成した実行ファイルを当該 Windows 環境に転送しても問題なく実行できました。

Comment: その「ところが prog.exe は実行できません。」の時にprog.exeは何処に存在してどうやって実行させようとしましたか？ そして表示されたエラーメッセージ等があれば省略せずに提示してください。

Comment: 統合開発環境上でプロジェクトを作ってコンパイルした、のではなくて手でコンパイルしたんでしょうか？　x64 native Tools Command Prompt をちゃんと経由しましたか？　あと、セキュリティソフトは何を使っていますか？　セキュリティソフトが邪魔している可能性があります。

Comment: 同じソース、同じコマンドを実行しましたが、特に問題なくEXEが作成されました。もしIDE上でプロジェクトを作成してビルドしても正しくEXEが出力されないなら、一度開発環境を入れ直してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: まともに動作していないレベルなので動作確認できる範囲は全部やってみましょう。あとセキュリティソフト＝ウイルス対策ソフトについても追記願います。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62801/ みたいな例もありますので。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

正体不明のエラーに付き合っていただきありがとうございました。
色々調べる中で原因がなんとなくわかった気がします。

ここまで説明しなかったのですが、当該 Windows 環境は VMWare Fusion の仮想マシンでした。
prog.c, prog.exe などが VMWare の共有ディレクトリ (vmware-host) に存在していたことが原因のようです。これらのディレクトリを仮想マシンのストレージ (C:) に移動させたところ、問題なくコンパイルできました。

VMWare のコミュニティでも似た質問? をしている方がおられました:
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Visual-Studio-cl-exe-in-guest-OS-bad-performance/td-p/1913013

質問でディレクトリの場所を `C:/Users/*/prog` としていたのは、C: 中に vmware-host へのリンクを張り、そちらを介してアクセスしていたためです。混乱された方がいらっしゃったらすみません。

Comment: 混乱というか状況が分からないので手探りでしたね。そういう特殊な環境であることは当初からあるいはせめて最初の追記の際に書いておいて欲しい所です。今後があるならこちらのヘルプ記事を参考に、出せる情報はすべて記述するようにしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 出せない情報があって、それがあることを記述すら出来ないなら、こうした公開の場で質問することはほとんど意味が無いでしょう。

Comment: @kunif 結果的にクリティカルだった環境情報が出せていなかったという点はありますが、個人的には少し言い方が強すぎるかなと感じました。出せない情報があったというよりかは、この情報を出す必要があることに気付きづらかったというのが実情ではないかな、と。実際主要なバージョン情報は最初から質問に載っていたので意識はなさっていたのではないかと推測していました。環境の情報は膨大で、何が一番の原因になりそうか見極めるのにはそれはそれでセンスが必要です。だから「全部書いてください」って言いがちですが、どこまでが全部なのかも場合によっては難しいんですよね……。それをコメントで引き出していくのも Q&A の在り方かなと思います。このサイトを Q&A のナレッジベースとしていくためには、今回のようにどこが原因か検討がつきづらい質問もうまくハンドリングしていく必要があるのではないかなと考えています。（……とここまで書きましたが、これはメタで話すべきだったかもしれませんね……すいません。）

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、まあ最後は蛇足でしたね。私も今回の情報は出せないものでは無く単に出すことを思い付かなかっただけだと思いますが、注意喚起も兼ねて強めに書いてしまいました。

Comment: 因みにですが、 Linux だと外部ボリューム (今回でいうホストOSのディレクトリ) は任意の場所にマウントでき、 GCC ではこのように外部ボリューム上でコンパイルしてもトラブルは発生しませんでした。ですから、仮想マシンであることで問題になるとは思っていませんでした。 OS ごとの挙動の違いを学習できるきっかけになったと思います。

Comment: 質問のような状況に遭遇した事が無かったので、仮想マシンの共有ディレクトリだとそのような事象がある、という情報は参考になりました。

Answer (score 1):

既にコメントが付いていますし、私も実際に同じ手順でプログラムを作成・実行できることを確認しました。そこから言えることは、手順には問題はありません。

あるとすれば、質問者さん固有の環境問題でしかありません。

- セキュリティソフトはインストールしていない環境
- Visual Studio 2022 を一旦削除して、再びインストールしてみた

などは考えられる問題の１つであり、どちらも原因ではなかったというのであれば、更に別問題なのでしょう。あらゆる可能性があり、特定できたとして、質問者さんにしか適用されないので、Q&Aの蓄積の観点では微妙だったりします…。

例えば、別のディレクトリで全く同じ操作を行ったら改善しませんか？

---

> プログラム `<実行ファイルの場所>` を開始できません。
> ファイルまたはディレクトリが壊れているため、読み取ることができません。

とのこと、イベントログにエラーが出ていませんか？ この実行に付随して発生するエラーや、もしくは日常的に何らかのエラーが。特にディスクの読み取りエラーなどが発生していないか気になります。

Answer (score 0):

コメントの応答が返る前に取り敢えず回答します。
コンパイルする前段階の作業が書かれていないのですが、この記事のように「開発者コマンド プロンプト」を起動していますか？
[Visual Studioを使いコマンドラインからC/C++のプログラムをコンパイルする](https://www.javadrive.jp/cstart/install/index5.html)
記事はVisual Studio 2017のものですが、Visual Studio 2022でも同様のものか、あるいはスタートメニューの表示は英語のまま(Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022とか)のものがあるはずです。

そして記事に質問と同等/類似のソースコードが提示されていますが、この程度ならばそのコンパイル時にオプション等無くても実行ファイルは出来ます。

別に質問のオプション指定方法が間違っているとか問題があるとかでは無さそうですが、紹介記事のようにそのままソースコードだけ指定してみてはどうでしょう？

それが出来てから色々とオプションを試していくのが良いと思われます。
[アルファベット順のコンパイラ オプション](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=msvc-170)
[カテゴリ別のコンパイラ オプション](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=msvc-170)

---

作業環境を設定するバッチファイルが`vcvars64.bat`で、`cl.exe`の出力メッセージの最初の行に以下の`for x86`が表示されるのは、整合性が取れていない感じがします。

```
Microsoft(R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31104 for x86
```

この末尾が`for x86`になるのは、`Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022`の`VsDevCmd.bat`, `x64_x86 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022`の`vcvarsamd64_x86.bat`, `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022`の`vcvars32.bat`あたりのはず。

ただ cl.exe の32bit/64bitが違っても、出来てくる .exe は動作するみたいなので、もしかしたらVS2022の環境が完全では無いか壊れているのかもしれません。

以下のような方法を試してみて、それでも解決しないようでしたら、Visual Studio Installerで修復インストールとかいったんアンインストール/再インストールを試してみた方が良いと思われます。

- VSCodeからではなく、スタートメニューからVS2022の各コマンドプロンプトを起動して、コンパイルしてみる。(質問の追記では済んでいる？)
- @radian さんのコメントのように、VSCodeやコマンドプロンプトではなく、Visual Studio のIDE上でプロジェクトを作成し、ビルドしてみる。

それから @774RR さんコメントのようにセキュリティソフトのチェックが影響しているなら、セキュリティソフトのログに何かしら記録が残りそうです。そちらとかあと加えてイベントログを調べてみるのも手かもしれません。

---

可能性は低い/あるいは既にチェック済みかもしれませんが、ユーザー名や作業フォルダまでの途中のパス名にShift-JISとかIBM拡張の全角文字とか半角文字でも何かの記号とか空白とかが含まれているということはありませんか？

あとはまったく別に、Visual Studio Community 2022をインストールする時に、`ワークロード`のタブでC++系のものを選んだだけでインストールしていませんか？

`個別のコンポーネント`のタブにC++系でも様々な種類とその版数違いのコンポーネントが示されていて、`ワークロード`で選んだだけだと割と多くのものがインストールされません。
それが影響する可能性は不明なのですが、もしかすると何かあるかもしれないので、C++系の(ゲーム系とか実験段階のものを除く)すべてのコンポーネントをインストールしてみてください。

---

上記あたりまでやっても駄目なら、いよいよデータのバックアップを取ってWindows11のクリーンインストールからやり直すパターンでしょうか。