# Rの色々なエラーで悩まされています

Tags: r

rglのライブラリを読み込もうとすると下記のエラーが出ます。
既にxfunがwin-libraryにもRのlibraryフォルダの中にあることも確認済みだし、何回かxfunとrglの再インストールもしていて、原因がわかりません。
rdsのインストールも一応してあります。

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
  DLL ‘xfun’ が見つかりません: このアーキテクチャ用にインストールされていないのでは？
```

当方Rを昨日ダウンロードしたばかりです。
これまでにインストールしたパッケージは以下の通りです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**実行環境**
Windows 10 Enterprise (64 bit) 21H1
R 4.2.0
RStudio Desktop 2022.02.2+485

**追記**
R, Rstudio, rtoolsをアンインストールして再度インストールし、
install.packagesを行おうとすると下記のエラーがでるようになり、
前の状況より悪化しました・・

```
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
```

Comment: とりあえずWindows10 Pro 21H2 64bitで他の版数やパッケージは合わせて(RStudioのGUIで1個1個)インストールしたところでは問題は発生していません。Windowsのクリーン再インストールが出来るならそこからやってみてはどうでしょう？ この辺の記事を参考にしてみました。[WindowsでのR/RStudioのインストール](https://okumuralab.org/~okumura/stat/R-win.html), [【2021年11月版】WindowsにR・RStudioをインストールする](https://qiita.com/otsukimi200624/items/b5d35ff3375a5e954878), [【初心者向け】RとRStudioのダウンロード・インストール 2021年9月版](https://zenn.dev/masayukeeeee/articles/96c7832de4dc40)

Comment: 一度R、Rstudios、rtoolsすべてアンインストールして入れなおしてみましたが、変わりませんでした・・

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。[RとRStudioをインストールするときのつまづきポイントとその対処法へのリンク](http://ryotamugiyama.com/2020/08/03/rinstall/) 中に書かれているOneDriveと類似関連で、OS自身を仮想マシンで動かしていて他とのリンクを貼ったフォルダをCコンパイラの作業フォルダにしたら正常な.exeが出来なかったという質問がありました。そんなこともあって今までの環境構築の影響を排除したWindowsのクリーン再インストールから試してみては？ とコメントしてみました。[cl.exe が壊れたバイナリしか出力しない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/86545/26370)

Comment: クリーン再インストールって、windowsをまっさらの状態に戻してから全部インストールしなおすってことですよね‥？できればそれは避けたいです‥
また、R, Rstudios, rtools全部インストールしなおしてもう一度install packagesやったら、今度は下記のエラーが出ました‥
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection

Comment: どうやらミラーサイトがうまく登録できてないみたいで、こんなエラーでました。対処法知ってたりしますか・・？⇒警告:  failed to download mirrors file ( URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv' を開けません ); using local file 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
 警告メッセージ: 
 download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) で: 
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached

Comment: 往々にしてそういう躊躇している部分が影響していたりします。今のPCでの再インストールが大変ならPCをもう1台借りるなりして用意し環境構築してみては？ それで上手くいくならそれを使い続けるなり今のPCで再インストールするなり決めれば良いでしょう。

Comment: 会社のPCなので、クリーンした場合ログインできなくなるかもしれないし、色々な部署に確認をとらないといけなくなるので、クリーンをできるだけしたくないんです・・違うPCで環境構築を試みるくらいならいいかもしれないですね、検討します。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 日本語版Windowsでのデータサイエンス環境構築は非常に難しいです。docker for windowsをインストールして `rocker/verse` のイメージで一度試してみてはいかがでしょうか。
これで動作すれば、OS依存の問題か切り分ける事ができます。

Answer (score 0):

日本語版WindowsでRを使うのは文字コードのトラブルなどが多く疲れるので、
Dockerを使ってLinux版を使用しては如何でしょうか。
特に`rocker`プロジェクトのイメージは多くのライブラリが始めからビルド検証済みでトラブルも少なくオススメです。

Docker for Windows をインストールしてから、

`docker run -d -p 8787:8787 rocker/verse`

と入力したら、モダンブラウザで `localhost:8787` を開くだけで使用開始できます。

RStudioは元々QtWebEngine(Electronに移行中)を用いたWebアプリのような構造ですから、
サーバ版も使用感はほぼ同じです。